# How to use symbol as a var in less?

Tags: css, less

The flex properties are too orderless.
I wanna write a less function to fix this problem.
just like:

```css
.flex(@grow:1,@shrink:1,@basis:auto){
 flex-grow:@grow;
 flex-shrink:@shrink;
 flex-basis:@basis;
}
```

About the "order" and "align",I want use a symbol-pre var,just like:

```css
//function======================
.flex(@order){
 @number:replace(@order,#,);
 order:@number;
}


//usage======================
.test{
  .flex(#2);
}

//result======================
.test{
  order:2;
}
```

How to realize this?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: @seven-phases-max

Comment: Why you write `.flex(#2)` if you can write `.flex(2)`?

Comment: I have use the function for another,the first one. @Justinas

Comment: I also can't understand the `#` thing, (after all you *can't use `#` in a mixin parameter since it's invalid CSS value). We need more details on what you mean with that `symbol-pre var` (how it is different from a regular var?)

Comment: Maybe I just want use the "#" as a var to distinguish different case.The following answer is right.But I want it don't need the "quote" symbol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding this correctly, it seems that you want to combine both of the mixins into one, and you're using the `#` to define that you're setting the `order`, not `grow`.

If you need to use the `#`, you can format it as a string and use mixin guards, like this:

```
.flex (@grow: 1, @shrink: 1, @basis: auto) when (isnumber(@grow)) {
    flex-grow: @grow;
    flex-shrink: @shrink;
    flex-basis: @basis;
}

.flex (@order) when (isstring(@order)) {
    @number: replace(@order,'#','');
    order: ~'@{number}';
}
```

Then use the mixin as usual for the top portion, and when you want to set the order, write it as:

```
.test {
    .flex('#2');
}
```

Comment: Yes,but the arguments should add the quote symbol.Thanks a lot

Comment: @iRuxu So it's just about number of typed characters? Just needed `.flex('#2')` instead of `.flex-order(2)` or `.flex-n(2)`? How about `.f(2)`?